# How to get all groups which is associated by user?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am new in python & django.
I have a users list where i want to get particular user assigned groups list in comma separated.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can obtain the set of `Group`s for a `User` with:

```
my_user.groups.all()
```

So we can make a comma-separated string containing the *name* of the `Group`s, with:

```
my_groups = ', '.join(map(str, my_user.groups.all()))
```

If you however want to do this for *all* `User`s (or a large set of `User`s), you should use `prefetch_related` first to load the related groups in bulk.

Comment: Thanks @Willem your answer help me lot. I have fetched groups list by this way in template file
`@register.simple_tag() 
def get_user_group(user_list_arr): 
 my_groups = ', '.join(map(str, user_list_arr.groups.all())) 
 return my_groups`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the below code to get all groups associated with a user. Make sure to import the Group.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
results = Group.objects.filter(user = request.user)
print(results)
```

The results will give you the list.